# Magento 2 upgrade from Merchant Beta to RC?

Tags: magento2, upgrade

Is there an established way to upgrade a Magento 2 Merchant Beta (master branch) install to the latest RC version? I haven't found a nice combination of commands / steps yet to complete an upgrade. The existing Merchant 2 Beta has the sample data already installed.

Comment: It's highly recommended to install from scratch, because of lot of changes in the core

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is related to a pre release version of Magento, more info here: http://meta.magento.stackexchange.com/questions/907/magento-2-questions-tagged-beta-alpha-pre-alpha-etc-quo-vadis

Comment: For information about how to upgrade Magento, please check the official documentation: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/comp-mgr/bk-compman-upgrade-guide.html

Answer (score 1):

What I did to update from Magento 2 1.0.0Beta to Magento 2 RC:

- Created backup of database and files
- Moved old Magento files to temp directory
- Placed Magento 2 RC files in the document root
- Added my old files:

  - app/etc/config.php and app/etc/env.php
  - extensions and my theme

After that I got an error about a resource. I fixed this with this script: https://mage2.pro/t/topic/130

After that Magento worked perfect.

Also make sure that a few things are changed:

- You should add a registration.php file to extensions and themes
- The scheme is changed, see Luma theme for an example. The scheme is changed from: ../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View to: urn:magento:framework:View

Answer (score 1):

1. `bin/magento setup:backup` to backup code base, media and database
2. If you deployed using `git clone` get latest version using `git pull`
3. Run `composer install`
4. Run `bin/magento setup:upgrade`
5. If you have any custom modules/themes, they will require `registration.php`